# Connection timeout on connecting via SMTP

Tags: java, spring, email, amazon-web-services

I have an issue with connecting to external SMTP via my Elastic Beanstalk - I get the timeout exception.

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
>   failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:
>   Couldn't connect to host, port: da16.domeny.com, 587; timeout -1;
>   nested exception is:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out.
>   Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't
>   connect to host, port: da16.domeny.com, 587; timeout -1;   nested
>   exception is:     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out;
>   message exceptions (1) are: Failed message 1:
>   com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
>   port: da16.domeny.com, 587; timeout -1;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connection

It seems that I cannot access the server. What am I doing wrong? My config in Spring is:

```
spring.mail.host=da16.domeny.com
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.port=587
```

It works when I run the jar locally.

Comment: Could you give us the stacktrace?

Comment: Are there any firewall rules that would prevent the application on Beanstalk from connecting to the SMTP server?

Comment: @jbird, I have default security group, with everything open.

Comment: @uksz Are you referring to the security group's inbound or outbound rules?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. Your code works locally, but fails on the server. The issue will be with the networking config. You can verify this by trying to connect to the port over telnet: `telnet smtpservername 587`. It will work locally, but will fail from your server. After this test you can hand the problem over to a designated network/security team.